# Application Insights to monitor IoT Edge (i.e. Docker containers)

Tags: docker, azure-application-insights, docker-for-windows, azure-iot-edge

I implemented some IoT Edge modules, which run inside Docker containers and I want to monitor them by using Azure Application Insights.
I tried to download the Docker Image for Application Insights, but it's not working since it seems the application is built for Linux, instead I have a Windows host.
This is the error:

```
>docker pull microsoft/applicationinsights
Using default tag: latest
latest: Pulling from microsoft/applicationinsights
03e1855d4f31: Extracting [==================================================>]  51.36MB/51.36MB
a3ed95caeb02: Download complete
9269ba3950bb: Download complete
6ecee6444751: Download complete
5b865d39f77d: Download complete
e7e5c0273866: Download complete
6a4effbc4451: Download complete
0ca84c702ddf: Download complete
f65c3d129381: Download complete
ef589ca5832a: Download complete
09284c30e414: Download complete
failed to register layer: re-exec error: exit status 1: output: Failed to OpenForBackup failed in Win32: open \\?\C:\ProgramData\docker\windowsfilter\a3b784c3d8da4c4eeca6b42111df7ddc25db2e134b9c655483a7bb144c6fc905\usr\share\man\man3\Locale::gettext.3pm.gz: 
The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect. (0x1f) \\?\C:\ProgramData\docker\windowsfilter\a3b784c3d8da4c4eeca6b42111df7ddc25db2e134b9c655483a7bb144c6fc905\usr\share\man\man3\Locale::gettext.3pm.gz
```

Do you know if there exists an image for Windows?

**UPDATE**
I have tried to collect performance by using [PerformanceCollectorModule](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/app-insights-performance-counters), with no luck since it seems that CPU and Memory metrics are not [supported](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/app-insights-performance-counters#performance-counters-in-aspnet-core-applications) from .NET Core Module.
Finally i tried to use [System.Diagnostics.PerformanceCounter](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Diagnostics.PerformanceCounter/) library, but my container has no permission to read those metrics. Although I tried to add Authenticated Users group to Performance Monitor Users and Performance Log Users groups.

```
Unhandled Exception: System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. (Access to the registry key 'Global' is denied.) ---> 
System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the registry key 'Global' is denied.
```

Does not exist any other way to monitor IoT Edge modules in Application Insights?

Comment: Are you trying to use Application Insights Status monitor to instrument existing applications? Image you specified above is only for monitoring Java applications and seems not to be updated or maintained in last 2 years

Comment: Actually my containers run .Net Core applications, precisely they are IoT Edge modules. Thus, I would like to monitor these containers and get some metric charts like the ones [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/app-insights-docker#perf-counters-by-host-activity-by-image). Does the image work only for Java applications?

Comment: Per location of help file, yes it's only for Java Application. If you instrumented your code with AppInsights SDK then it will work the same way both VM as well as container. If you look for application insights status monitor then look at my blog post (https://artisticcheese.wordpress.com/2018/03/13/monitoring-windows-docker-containers-using-application-insights-status-monitor/)

Comment: Thanks for the reference, but that should work only for web apps running on IIS, shouldn't it?

Comment: Yes, it has very limited applicability but for those of us who have no way to monitor containers based of IIS it's actually very usefull. For you probably the only solution is to properly instrument through AppInsights SDK your code

Comment: To use Application Insights SDK for custom modules is very straightforward, I built a C# module that uses that, see here: https://github.com/seb-dataworks/azureiotedge/tree/master/IotEdgePerformanceTestMonitor

Comment: Thanks silent, but I instrumented my module to send trace on AI and it works. The problem is that I cannot find a way to collect Performance Counter (e.g. CPU%) or set up [Live Metrics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/app-insights-performance-counters)

Answer (score 0):

I followed "[Monitor Docker applications in Application Insights](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/app-insights-docker)" tutorial and get my edge docker container host performance like this:

[image]

My settings:

Host: Windows 10 desktop

Docker Engine: [Docker for Windows](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/install/)

Docker images: Application Insights image and Azure IoT Edge

Start AI image followed "[Run the Application Insights monitor on your host](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/app-insights-docker#run-the-application-insights-monitor-on-your-host)".

Start IoT Edge followed "[Deploy your first IoT Edge module from the Azure portal to a Windows device](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-edge/quickstart)".

You can have a try to see if it helps.

Comment: It doesn't work for me because AI Docker image is for Linux, instead I have Windows containers.

Comment: I cannot switch to Linux now, and Docker LCOW is not production ready.

Comment: is there anything that is not deprecated? I am trying to monitor host and preferably i'd like to have any monitoring software contenerized... is it even possible?